# SAP MD04 - Overview Tree Export

Tags: sap-erp

I would like to find a way to export the data given by the SAP ERP transaction code `MD04` - overview tree in Excel.
I don't understand what will be the best approach.
Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Regs
S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this workaround:
You have to use 2 Functional Module CS_BOM_EXPL_MAT_V2 + MD_STOCK_REQUIREMENTS_LIST_API

In the INFOSET Data Reading Program I've used the CS_BOM_EXPL_MAT_V2 for the BOM Explosion.

```js
REPORT  RSAQDVP_TEMPLATE .
data:
  STPOX                          type STPOX                         ,
  it_data type standard table of STPOX                         .

field-symbols: <struc> type STPOX                         .

* !! the following comment MUST NOT BE CHANGED !!
*<QUERY_HEAD>

*  (select your data here into internal table IT_DATA)
call function 'CS_BOM_EXPL_MAT_V2'
  EXPORTING
    auskz = 'X'
    capid = p_capid
    datuv = p_datuv
    emeng = u_qty
    mehrs = 'X'
    mtnrv = p_mtnrv
    werks = p_werks
  TABLES
    stb   = it_data.

loop at it_data assigning <struc>.
  move-corresponding <struc> to STPOX                         .
* !! the following comment MUST NOT BE CHANGED !!
*<QUERY_BODY>
endloop.
```

Than I've added Additional Field calling the MD_STOCK_REQUIREMENTS_LIST_API.

```js
CLEAR MNG01_FM.

  call function 'MD_STOCK_REQUIREMENTS_LIST_API'
    EXPORTING
      matnr = STPOX-IDNRK
      werks = p_werks
    TABLES
      mdezx  = it_da2.


   READ TABLE it_da2 ASSIGNING <struct2> WITH KEY DELKZ = 'SB'.
   if sy-subrc = 0.
      MNG01_FM = <struct2>-MNG01.
    endif.
```